# non Identified relationship and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

if i have two non identified relationships, `FK_one` and `FK_two`.
The only way, that i cant put them as a single primary key is when i add PK to the `FK_one` and `FK_two`, but if i do that, the relation is now an identified.

So my question is: i can only  have two foreign keys as a PK if they are an Identified relationship, correct? otherwise they can't be used as PK even if I have two or more FK (non Identified relationships)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An identified relationship is "identified" with 2 or more FKs as primary keys and without a surrogate key. So you end up with a composed primary key, but as far as I know you can have all the primary keys you want but that's not good for the server performance.

Comment: basically you confirm: i can only have two foreign keys as a PK if they are an Identified relationship?

Comment: You can have all the FKs as PK you want. In the moment you make a FK a PK you are creating an identified relationship between does 2 tables.